# Getting an AuthToken using Siesta via Password Grant

Tags: siesta-swift

new to both Swift and Siesta... Trying to make a "password" grant type request. I used the code located [here](https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/guide/configuration/) (the block at the very bottom). My code is:

```
var authToken: String??
var tokenCreationResource: Resource { return resource("oauth/v2/token") }


func refreshTokenOnAuthFailure(request: Request) -> Request {
    return request.chained {
        guard case .failure(let error) = $0.response,  // Did request fail…
            error.httpStatusCode == 401 else {           // …because of expired token?
                return .useThisResponse                    // If not, use the response we got.
        }
        return .passTo(
            self.createAuthToken().chained {             // If so, first request a new token, then:
                if case .failure = $0.response {           // If token request failed…
                    return .useThisResponse                  // …report that error.
                } else {
                    //print($0.response)
                    return .passTo(request.repeated())       // We have a new token! Repeat the original request.
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
func userAuthData() -> [String: String] {
    return [
        "username": "username",
        "password": "password",
        "grant_type": "password",
        "client_id": "abc1234567",
        "client_secret": "1234567abc"
    ]

}

func createAuthToken() -> Request {
    print("requestingToken")
    return tokenCreationResource
        .request(.post, urlEncoded: userAuthData())
        .onSuccess {
            self.authToken = $0.jsonDict["access_token"] as? String  // Store the new token, then…
            print($0.jsonDict) //*****SEE MY NOTE BELOW ABOUT THIS LINE
            self.invalidateConfiguration()                    // …make future requests use it
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to set the authToken variable... In troubleshooting the $0.jsonDict variable in the createAuthToken() function seems to be empty. The line noted prints `[:]`

If I change the `print($0.jsonDict)` to `print($0)` I see the full response including the "content" section which displays the results I would have expected to be in the jsonDict

If it matters, my server implementation is Symfony using FOSOauthServerBundle. All this works fine if I just manually do a request in the browser and like I said the "content" of the response shows my token, I just can't seem to access it via the `.jsonDict["access_token"]`

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact same issue with the example code - you need to remove

```
standardTransformers: [.text, .image]
```

from the Service constructor (or include .json).